# Установить изображение на рабочий стол

Tags: java

Можно ли из приложения на Java, которое запускается с помощью JNLP-файла (Java Web Strart), установить изображение на рабочий стол? Чтобы это работало хотя бы в Windows.

Comment: > Runtime.getRuntime().exec(fileDirectory);

или средствами JNI

Comment: А какую команду выполнять в exec?

Comment: в exec передаюся команды как в командную строку винды, врятли это тебе подойдет, но с ее помощью, ты можешь запускать сторонние программы
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(calc);
запустит калькулятор

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На SO был подобный вопрос. Ответ принят, но лично я не пробовал (за отсутствием соответствующей среды для проверки)

[Can I change my Windows desktop wallpaper programmatically in Java/Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750372/)